# PHP send SMS with nexmo

Tags: php, vonage

i'm using nexmo services to send SMS to specific number **IN HEBREW**, but the message arrived  as %D7%AA%D7. (My language is PHP), this is my code:

```
$message = $_REQUEST["message"];

//Build the url 
$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query(
    [
      'api_key' =>  '******',
      'api_secret' => '*******',
      'to' => '9725433131',
      'from' => '4416329600',
      'text' => urlencode($message)
    ]
);
//Send the data
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

Comment: try adding `'type' => 'unicode'` in the post params

Comment: Where exactly i suppose to insert this line ?

Comment: alongside with the rest of the post params, after the `text` parameter for instance.

Comment: Can you please show me in the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `type` parameter in the request.

```
//Build the url 
$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query(
[
      'api_key' =>  '******',
      'api_secret' => '*******',
      'to' => '9725433131',
      'from' => '4416329600',
      'text' => urlencode($message),
      'type' => 'unicode'
    ]
);
```

You can [find](https://docs.nexmo.com/messaging/sms-api/api-reference) more info in the nexmo documentation page.